# Divide sum as a result of checkboxes toggled javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, toggle

I'm having an issue. I have an accumulated sum of gathered donations, ex. 10€. Then I have a number of NGO's that you can choose to donate to. 
You have the opportunity to toggle on/off which NGO's you would like to support. Either you can choose to donate to all of them which means each NGO will receive 10€ / 3 = 3,33 € each. You can choose two and the allocation is going to be 10 € / 2 = 5€ each etc.

I'm having issues of finding a way to do this in javascript. Could you lead me the right way? Thanks.

```js
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}

function myFunction() {
    var y = 5;
    var x = y / 3;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="Velgørenhed.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Velgørenhed.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Tilbage knap  -->
<button id="tilbage" onclick="goBack()">Tilbage</button>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="WHO" checked> Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation WHO<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="Plastic Change" checked> Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation Plastic Change<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="Sea Turtle Conservancy" checked> Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation Sea Turtle Conservancy<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>y = 5, calculate x = y / 3, and display x:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<!-- Log ud knap -->
<button id="logOut" onclick="logOut()">Log ud</button>

<script>
    function logOut() {
        document.location.href = "1logInd.html";
    }
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must be having NGOs name as list. So when your function gets called, check the number of checkboxes (.checked property for that checkbox will be true), maintain a counter for this checkboxes, then divide the donation amount by counter value.

Comment: first thing: your checkboxes all have the same name. This is never going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the selected checkboxes and use the resulting length to divide by the total amount to be donated across all organizations.

```js
const form = document.forms[0];

form.elements['calc-btn'].addEventListener('click', function() {
  let total = parseInt(form.elements['amount'].value, 10);
  let count = selectedCheckboxes(form, 'organisation').length;
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = average(total, count).toFixed(2);
});

triggerEvent(form.elements['calc-btn'], 'click'); // Calculate on load

function average(total, count) {
  return count > 0 ? total / count : 0;
}

function selectedCheckboxes(form, name) {
  return Array.from(form.elements[name]).filter(c => c.checked);
}

function triggerEvent(el, eventName) {
  var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.result-display {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <h2>Donation Form</h2>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Organizations</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="WHO" checked>
      Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation WHO<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="Plastic Change" checked>
      Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation Plastic Change<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="Sea Turtle Conservancy" checked>
      Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation Sea Turtle Conservancy<br>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Donation amount (€)</legend>
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="10.00" />
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" id="calc-btn" value="Calculate" />
  <div class="result-display">Calculated donation amount: <span id="result">0</span>€</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great. Can you explain what the js exactly do line for line? I'm not 100% sure atm and trying to get a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

`$(".orgs input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;` will return how many checkboxes are selected. The total amount of donation will be split to number of organisations selected.

```js
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}

function myFunction() {    
    // let's suppose that we have 20$ donated
    var totalDonations = 20;
    
    var noOfChckSelected = $(".orgs input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    console.log("no of organisations selectd: " + noOfChckSelected)
    
    var donationPerOrg = totalDonations / noOfChckSelected;
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = donationPerOrg;
    
    console.log("each organisation will receive: " + donationPerOrg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="Velgørenhed.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Velgørenhed.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Tilbage knap  -->
<button id="tilbage" onclick="goBack()">Tilbage</button>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
<div class = "orgs">
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="WHO" checked> Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation WHO<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="Plastic Change" checked> Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation Plastic Change<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="organisation" value="Sea Turtle Conservancy" checked> Vælg velgørenhedsorgsnisation Sea Turtle Conservancy<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<p>y = 5, calculate x = y / 3, and display x:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<!-- Log ud knap -->
<button id="logOut" onclick="logOut()">Log ud</button>

<script>
    function logOut() {
        document.location.href = "1logInd.html";
    }
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full scope of where you are getting the accumulated sum of donation, but I can assume that the checkboxes with "organization" name are the NGO's. In that case, you can do something like

```
var numOrgsDonateTo = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='organisations[]']:checked").length
var allocation = sumDonation / numOrgsDonateTo
```

The first line is basically searching for all input with name = "organisations" that are checked and counting how many there are